# Multiple outputs regression with one custome metrics IoU

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have users who segmennted objects on images by boxes `[Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax]`

Also, I have true boxes `[Xmin_true, Ymin_true, Xmax_true, Ymax_true]`

I need to improve users' labels trying to predict real boxes. The metrics is the IoU (intersection over union) between users' labels and true labels.

I tried to predict X_min, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax separately with `LightGBM`, but the problem is that it didn't optimize the IoU.

What is the best approach for this problem? As I see, boosting won't work for this case, it should be some kind of neural new with few outputs and one custom metrics such as IoU.

Could you suggest something to start?

Now my code looks like this but it predicts constant values for X, Y

```
NN=Sequential()
NN.add(Dense(128,activation='linear',input_dim=np.shape(X_train)[1]))
NN.add(Dropout(0.1))
NN.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
NN.add(Dropout(0.1))
NN.add(Dense(4,activation='linear'))

NN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=[IoU])
set_random_seed(0)

NN.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=2,
        validation_split=0.2, shuffle = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom loss function like [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2018/discussion/51553) and apply it according to [that link](https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-and-metrics-c07ca130a618)